# `lshw` doesn't show my CD/DVD and I cannot eject it

Tags: drivers, dvd

The solution seems to be putting a DVD in the tray, as I've read, then it will be detected. But my computer has no physical eject button, how do I solve this?

There's no folder `sr0` no `/dev/cdrom` or anything similar. Just `/media/cdrom` which contains nothing.

Acer Aspire E5-573

Debian 11

Comment: `sr0` is not a folder, but a device name in `/dev/`. But I guess that doesn't exist either!

Comment: Can you tell us what happens when you run `cat /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info` ?

Comment: @MarcusMüller It says `cat: /proc/sys/dev/cdrom/info: No such file or directory` :/

Comment: Ok, so there's definitely nothing in your system that detects the presence of an optical drive. If I read the internet correctly, the Acer Aspire E5-573 didn't come with an optical drive from factory, but with a slot for self-installation. Can you check whether the UEFI/Bios setup (reboot into that using: `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`) detects the drive? If not, it might need to be enabled in there; if that's not the case, improperly connected or faulty drive.

Comment: It requires the `sg` module to be loaded does it not?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Under the BOOT section for priority order, both USB CDROM and ATAPI CDROM appear. Have no clue if this is what you were asking me to look for.

Comment: I don't know what your system setup UI looks like, boot typically, on another screen there's something that lists detected drives.

Comment: @Bib yes, but this being debian 11, that's going to be automatically loaded.

Comment: @MarcusMüller unless it's not being loaded, hence the question.

Comment: @Bib but why would it not being loaded? I'm all for looking into possible reasons, but with a modern Linux, which otherwise boots, why would `sg` not get loaded if there's a CDROM drive on SATA, visible to the system? That seems pretty unlikely!

Comment: @MarcusMüller who knows... Perhaps it's blacklisted, perhaps the op built their own kernel and never selected it. If the more logical reasons do not produce an answer, then you have to look at the more illogical ones. After all, we both know it should work.